# Application of Mean-Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I wish to prove that the following equation $$x^2 +3x = \cos(x)$$

has precisely two roots. Since this is equivalent to the quadratic equation $$x^2+3x - \cos (x) = 0$$

let $f(x) = x^2 +3x - \cos(x)$. Because of the quadratic term, this equation has precisely two roots, which is equivalent to the statement : $f(x)$ intersects the horizontal axis at two points. Let $f(a),f(b)$ denote those points.

$f$ is continuous everywhere and differentiable everywhere, including some arbitrary interval $[a,b],(a,b)$. According to the mean value theorem, there exists a point $c\in (a,b)$ such that $$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=\frac{0-0}{b-a}=0$$

We can then apply Rolle's theorem to conclude the proof. Is it necessary in this case to restric the interval $[a,b]$ into some appropriate sub-interval of $\Bbb{R}$? I was thinking $[-\pi, \pi]$ initially, but then didn't see the point of it.

Comment: The equation $x^2+3x-\cos(x)=0$ is **not** a quadratic equation because of the cosine term.

Comment: As Anurag A. points out, your equation is not a quadratic, but you are right concerning the 2 roots. To show this, use differentiation...

Comment: Another equation $x^2 - 200\cos x$ will clearly have many more than two roots. When $x= -4\pi,-2\pi, 0,2\pi, 4\pi$ then $\cos x=1$ and $200\cos x=200 > (4\pi)^2\ge x^2$ so $x^-200\cos x < 0$.  But for $x=-3\pi,\pi,\pi,3\pi$ then $\cos x=-1$ and $x^2-200\cos x=x^2 +200> 0$ so there are are roots between $-4\pi$ and $-3\pi$ and between $-3\pi$ and $-2\pi$ as so on.  So there are at least $8$ roots.... despite the quadratic power.

Comment: $x^2 +3x -\cos x=0\implies x^2 +3x=\cos x\implies x^2+3x +\frac 94 =\cos x+\frac 94\implies (x+\frac 32)^2 =\cos x+\frac 94\implies x+\frac 32=\pm\sqrt{\cos x+\frac 94}\implies x=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{4\cos x+ 9}}2$.  But that's not the end of it. We have the value of $x$ *in terms of $x$*.  So although the quadratic equation is a valid way to find at most $2$ roots for a quadratic *polynomial* it is *not* a valid way for an equation in the form of $ax^2 + bx + c$ where $a,b,c$ are *not* constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I shall point: $x^2 + 3x - \cos(x) = 0$ is NOT a quadratic equation. Thus, your statement:

> Because of the quadratic term, this equation has precisely two roots

is incorrect.

To convince you better, consider the "quadratic equation": $x^2 - 2^x = 0.$ This happens to have $3$ roots. ($2$ and $4$ are clear roots. I leave it to you to show the *existence* of a negative root.)

Moreover, it isn't even necessary that an actual quadratic equation has two (distinct real) roots. For example, consider: $x^2 = 0$ and $x^2 + 1 = 0$.

---

The actual solution:
We do this in two parts:

**Part 1.** Showing that there exist at least 2 roots.
Let $f(x) = x^2 + 3x - \cos(x)$. Note that $f(100) > 0$ and $f(-100) > 0$. Also, note that that $f(0) < 0$. Thus, by the intermediate value theorem, $f$ has at least two roots, one in $(-100, 0)$ and one in $(0, 100)$.

**Part 2.** Showing that there are at most 2 roots.
Suppose that there are three distinct real roots: $a, b, c$. We shall arrive at a contradiction.

WLOG, we may assume that $a < b < c$.
Now, we have $f(a) = f(b)$ and thus, by Rolle's theorem, we have that $f'(\alpha) = 0$ for some $\alpha \in (a, b)$.
We similarly have $f'(\beta) = 0$ for some $\beta \in (b, c)$.

Now, applying Rolle's theorem to $f'$ on $(\alpha, \beta)$, we see that there exists $\gamma \in (\alpha, \beta)$ such that $f''(\gamma) = 0.$ However, we note that:

$$f''(\gamma) = 2 + \cos(\gamma) \ge 2 + (-1) = 1 > 0,$$

a contradiction.

---

I leave the justification of usage of the theorems up to you. (Namely, intermediate value theorem and Rolle's theorem.)

Answer (score 1):

The second derivative is $2+\cos(x)>0$, Thus the first derivative is monotonically increasing from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, so that it has only a single root. This means, that your function is first decreasing and then increasing. Hope you can go on from there...